# Is my question really that bad or I just pissed off someone?

Tags: discussion

I tried to ask a question on Stackoverflow and I really pissed someone off there. So I re-asked here on programmers, but pissed off some another people because I tried to delete my duplicate question.

Today when I login and find my question closed (again).

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/210381/do-analytics-services-build-their-own-database-or-using-existing-ones

So may I ask, is my question really opinion based? (Compared to other questions here on programmers.stackexchange.com)

Or am I just pissed of someone so they are really want my question on hold so no one could answer it?

Answer (score 7):

I looked into your question closure and do not see any evidence that the users you mentioned are treating you unfairly on Programmers.  I am not a moderator on StackOverflow and do not have high enough reputation there to see certain information so I can't speak for their behaviour on that site.

We take rudeness and personal attacks very seriously and do not tolerate them from any user so we will always look into allegations like this.

After reviewing the question closure I am in agreement with the community.  You provided many details about your design and your goals which is great, however it seems to be a very complex design and the question isn't clear.  Your question boils down to a request for design review which isn't the kind of question we look for on StackExchange.  It is a question that really deserves a good long discussion with back and forth commentary.  The Q&A format of StackExchange doesn't lend itself to this well so we generally put these on hold.

I suggest looking into our Chat feature on StackExchange and see if anybody would like to help review your design, or if you have a specific problem or query about your design proposal then try editing your question to narrow the focus so we can look into reopening the question.

Comment: fair enough. I'll see myself out.